# Dose anyone know something like PropertyEditor or PropertyGrid in SWT?

Tags: java, swt, propertygrid, propertyeditor

I'm working on a game editor with SWT/JFACE. I'm looking for something like `PropertyEditor` or `PropertyGrid` (like `PropertyGrid` in C#) in SWT, to provide modification of objects in the editor. Does anyone know something like that? Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to develop standalone SWT application (without Eclipse RCP) you could use this open source [library](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/PropertyTable).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm looking for. Thank you so much. Sorry for this delayed response.

Answer (score 0):

Using data bindings might be what you're looking for.

https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/features/swt/data_binding/example

Comment: Thank you for your kindly help, but I'm afraid what I expect goes further than data binding. New class would be loaded as plugin into the editor and the property editor must be able to use introspection to get the members of the class and enable user to edit the objects' members. I used to use PropertyGrid in C#, but I cannot find any in Java.